# Question: Something's wrong--perhaps a missing \item

Tags: errors, conditionals

My code is as following:

```
\begin{denotation}
    \iffalse
        \item[符号1]    解释1
        \item[符号2]    解释2
    \fi
\end{denotation}
```

I have `\item` in my code. What's the real problem?

Comment: you have surrounded the `\item` with `\iffalse` which essentially comments them out as if they were not there.

Answer (score 2):

`\iffalse...\fi`  is a conditional that is always false, so the content is always skipped and the `\item` that you show are never executed, hence the error shown.